# Apply 'exists' query on array of nested objects in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a json document in elasticsearch complete/user with the following structure:

```
"_source":{
"experiences":[
{experience 1}, {experience 2}, ... , {experience n}

]

}
```

The structure of experience object in the experiences array is as follows:

```
{
    "company":

    {
        "industry": industry of the comany,
        "name": company name,
​        ... other fields
    },
    "start_date": date when person joined company,
    ... other fields
}
```

I want to find all such documents where neither of the experiences in experiences array have company.industry field i.e. all the experiences must have this field missing. Is there any query that I can use?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the `experiences` field of type `nested`?

Comment: Yes @Val. The experience field in experiences array is nested. The second json corresponds to its structure. Thanks

Comment: It will be helpful if you can post your mapping as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this out:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
         "exists": {"field" : "experiences.company.industry"}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This query will return all the documents where **company.industry** of **all experience** in **experiences array** is **missing** or **null**.

Example:

```
"_source": {
  "experiences": [
    {
      "company": {
        "name": "company name"
      }
    },
    {
      "company": {
        "industry": null,
        "name": "company name"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What this query will not return:

```
"_source": {
  "experiences": [
    {
      "company": {
        "industry": "IT",
        "name": "company name"
      }
    },
    {
      "company": {
        "industry": null,
        "name": "company name"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: Hi @Technocrat Sid. I had tried the above query but it returns documents in which some of the experience in experiences array have null/missing industry value while some have not null. This query works well if the field is not in array objects.

Comment: Hi @NishantGarg, according to the statement "all the experiences must have this field missing" in your question. I have provided the answer, maybe you can modify your question so that I can follow along. This query even works if you've got null values.